# how to use lat/long point converted into a blob in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, geography

I have a database which has a table that has a geography point datatype migrated into oracle. After the convertion, the column is now a BLOB. How can I get the lat/long from the BLOB?

A simple DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE example to print the lat long from the BLOB will suffice. I'll try to figure out how to do other geographical operations later.

Comment: Is it truly a BLOB?  You can use the [DESCRIBE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve019.htm#i2697562) command in SQL*Plus to find out.  If it is a BLOB, you'll have to go back to whatever tool you used to convert the data.  If it's SDO_GEOMETRY (Oracle's built-in data type for storing spatial data), check the documentation for information on [how it represents the data](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_objrelschema.htm#i1004087) and [some examples](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11830/sdo_objrelschema.htm#i1001898).

Comment: @BrianCamire DESCRIBE shows it's a BLOB column. There are other tables automatically generated after the migration that's named DR$SPATIAL_TABLENAME$I, DR$SPATIAL_TABLENAME$K, DR$SPATIAL_TABLENAME$N, DR$SPATIAL_TABLENAME$R. The last table contains "rownum" and "data" column which are int and BLOB datatype, respectively. Any clues? Should I recheck the migration process again?

Comment: Those look like system tables produced by [Oracle Text](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/text.112/e16594/aoptim.htm).  It is unlikely that your spatial data would be located in these tables.